# Retrieve specific data from MySQL table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with just one table with two columns: `kode` and `name`.

`name` is where I save province, city and village names.

`kode` is where I save province, city and village ids.

Here's an example :

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Kode                | Name                     |
--------------------------------------------------
| 61                  | West Borneo              |
| 61.04               | Ketapang City            |
| 61.04.25            | Sei Melayu Rayak         |
| 61.04.25.2001       | Beringin Jaya            |
--------------------------------------------------
```

`61` is province name, `61.04` is city name, `61.04.25` is subdistric name and `61.04.25.2001` is village name.

Usually I use this query to extract data from my database.

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM village ORDER BY name ASC");

    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    if($rowCount > 0){
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            echo 'Village ID : '.$row['id_kel'].', Village Name : '.$row['nama'].'';
        }
    }else{
        echo "Village name not avaliable'";
    }
```

But, I think it wont work if I want to retrive data if I just have 2 columns.

How can I retrive this data if I just have data like this? 
Is it possible to export for each ID into sql file / put into another or more specific table like province, city, and village?

The reason why I'm doing this is because I want to implement a dynamic select option.

Answer (score 0):

A quick advice is to make your table multi level (i.e location_l1 => province name and so on.

If you want to normalize it, you will need to create 4 tables, province, city, subdistrict and village, each have a unique id, the name and the reference id of the superior level.

Moving on to your second question, you might want to explode your id using the defined separator and write them into some file. This will keep track of your records, where you will then control the insertion into your updated model

Comment: i want to create different table, but this database is the only database i have and it contain all village name in Indonesia. I have another one from different source, but it just have few village name.